# Move newsletter block before footer start, Luma, magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, newsletter-block

Trying to move **newsletter** from footer outside of it(Footer) in **Luma theme**, magento 2.

curent structure

```
<footer>
    // HERE I WANT TO HAVE THE NEWSLETTER
    <div class="footer content">
        // blocks, newsleter, etc..
    </div>
</footer>
```

tried with

```
<move element="form.subscribe" destination="footer" before="-" />
```

but this is placing the newsletter as **first block** inside

```
footer.content
```

Or another way can be to place newsletter outside of the end of page content. 
Tried too, is setting 1st block in content but not outside.

Any help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this : `<move element="form.subscribe" destination="footer-container" before="-"/>`

Flush cache after update that changes.

Comment: Welcome happy to help you